# How to enter and exit immersive mode in Android IceCreamSandwich (API 15)

Tags: android

When the following code is put into the onCreate method of my main activity my app should enter immersive mode.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_original_);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

The problem is that code only works on API 19 and higher and I want to support API 15 or 16 (strongly prefer 15) and above. How can I enter and exit a immersive-like mode in my app when it is using API 15/16 or above?

Answer (score 2):

With API15 it's impossible: if you check the flags they are introduced only in API16. But don't spend energy and time for API14-15 that are almost abandoned, and almost all upgraded to 16.

However you can try, before the setContent:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Instead I'm having trouble to keep the immersive mode in API16. It always put back once screen is tapped and interface is not interactive, basically it's always in "lean back". According to this we need to split the code.

**EDIT 18/10/2015**

Put the 2 static functions in an Utility class and call them from the activities.

```
private final Handler mSystemUiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
    Utils.hideSystemUI(getWindow());
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume called!");
    super.onResume();
    //Allow button disappear/appear when keyboard shows/hides
    handleSystemUi();
    mSystemUiHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, DELAY_FULLSCREEN);
}

private void handleSystemUi() {
    // Create the change listener to listen for flag changes and reset IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    enter code hereView decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ( (visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == 0
                    || (visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0 ) {
                mSystemUiHandler.removeMessages(0);
                mSystemUiHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, DELAY_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static void hideSystemUI(final Window window) {
    if (hasKitkat()) {
        // KITKAT (4.4) mode: hide the soft nav bar (Immersive mode)
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // [API 14] hide nav bar!
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // [API 16] // hide nav bar, always pretend the nav bar is missing
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE // [API 16] fix screen resolution for app to minimum UI state
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // [API 16] always pretend we're fullscreen, even when not fullscreen
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // [API 16] hide status bar, fullscreen mode
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY // [API 19] hide everything, and fade it if/when it comes back
        );

    } else if (hasHoneycomb()) {
        // HONEYCOMB to JELLYBEAN (3.0 - 4.3) mode: hide status bar, allow nav bar
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE // [API 16] fix screen resolution for app to minimum UI state
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // [API 16] always pretend we're fullscreen, even when not fullscreen
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // [API 16] hide status bar, fullscreen mode
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE // [API 14] dim on-screen UI
        );
    }
}

//In case you need to show manually
public static void showSystemUI(Window window) {
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Unfortunately that is not enough: There are devices that also want these:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged hasFocus="+hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        mSystemUiHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mSystemUiHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, DELAY_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        mSystemUiHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, DELAY_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```